# how to only include long description for each category in Pie chart's legend?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a number of categories defined with uppercase alphabet letters (say 'Cat-1', 'Cat-2', ... 'Cat-10') and I would like to display in a [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html)  with a [Pie dataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DefaultPieDataset.html) the short names on the pie itself and the long descriptions in the legend, instead of the long descriptions appearing **both** on the legend and on the pie as shown in the following example (which results in a very cluttered pie due to the long descriptions):

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [LabelGenerator](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/PieSectionLabelGenerator.html) to generate different labels.

Here is some sample code:

```
public JFreeChart createChart()
{
  chart = ...
  PiePlot plot = (PiePlot)chart.getPlot();
  plot.setLabelGenerator(new CustomLabelGenerator());

  return chart;
}

public class CustomLabelGenerator implements PieSectionLabelGenerator {
  public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key)
  {
    return "my Label for " + dataset.getValue(key);
  }
  public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

See also [this thread form the JFreeChart forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=114948) for some more details.

Comment: `CategoryPlot` does not contain a `setLabelGenerator` method: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing up different sources of information. PiePlot has this method and is what you are actually using. I hopefully sorted this out in my answer now. Let me know if there is still something wrong.